# What is Mono shared runtime?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am building an android app on Xamarin. Every time I run the app on my device for testing, it uninstalls the shared runtime and installs Mono shared runtime on the device.

I cannot find what is Mono shared runtime exactly. I also want to know whether installing it on the device is harmful in any way, and how can I rollback the changes.

Comment: it is a *virtual machine* for running .net code on Android

Comment: Is it installed temporarily or permanently on the device?

Comment: it is just an application, and is installed same way as any other application. Your own app needs it to run on Android

Comment: Why does it say uninstalling runtime on every build then?

Comment: have no idea. Probably there is some problem with your environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is Mono shared runtime?

Refer to the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process

The `shared runtime` is a pair of additional Android packages which provide the `Base Class Library` (`mscorlib.dll`, etc.) and the Android binding library (`Mono.Android.dll`, etc.). Debug builds rely upon the shared runtime in lieu of including the Base Class Library and Binding assemblies within the Android application package, allowing the Debug package to be smaller.

The `shared runtime` may be disabled in `Debug` builds by setting the `$(AndroidUseSharedRuntime)` property to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

> Change it from the configuration manager
>
> Right Click on your SOLUTION(not project) -> Properties -> Now under
>   configuration for each project, select "Release" selecting Release
>   will automatically uncheck "Use Shared Runtime"