# What the word “shared” really means in Xamarin Shared Mono Runtime?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

When you install debug builds on android Xamarin doesn't include Mono runtime in the app instead of this it uses the thing called Shared mono runtime ? I'm curious what the word shared really means? Does is mean that the single instance of the runtime will be lunched and all debug builds(of different apps) will run in this single instance of Mono runtime, or this means that Mono will be delivered to the device only once and all debug builds will run its own instance of that shared runtime(So it will just not be delivered with every app install)
P.S. Although this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014499/what-is-mono-shared-runtime) looks similar its accepted answer just copy-pastes some ambiguous info from Xamarin docs which is not very informative and doesn't really answers the question

Comment: "this means that Mono will be delivered to the device only once and all debug builds will run its own instance of that shared runtime(So it will just not be delivered with every app install)", that's it. You can easily get that out by running a few experiments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Mono shared runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014499/what-is-mono-shared-runtime)